# Incoming array values into local registers?

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, sparc

If I have something that looks like this:

```
void func (unsigned long arr[]) {

}
```

In assembly, how do I get the values in the arr[0] and arr[1] into local registers and pass arr back out?

This is what I tried:

```
func:
    save %sp, -(92 + 8) & -8, %sp    ! save 8 bytes

    st %i0, [%fp-8]

    sll %g0, 2, %l0
    add %l0, -8, %l0
    ld [%fp+%l0], %l0                ! value of arr[0] should be in %l0


    ..........                       ! something similar to load arr[1]


    ld [%fp-8], %i0
```

This didn't work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Oh. This is for an assignment. How would I get the values of arr[0] and arr[1]?

Comment: `unsigned long arr[]` is identical to `unsigned long* arr` when it's a parameter.

Comment: I know that's why I stored at %fp-8. but i don't know how to access value at %fp-4

Comment: There's only one parameter, the pointer. The pointer points to arr[0] and arr[1] is in the next word. There's nothing interesting in %fp-4. If you want to pass arr back out, you have to return it, but your function is void. C is pass by value ... you can't change the caller's argument ... this is basic stuff.

Comment: When you say "pass arr back out", do you really mean that you want to change the content of the array? It helps to be precise.

Comment: I do "ld [%fp-8], %l1" and then "ld [%l1], %l1" for arr[0]. How do I get the value of the next word?

Comment: You don't know how to index off a pointer? Better hit the books ... or just look at some generated asm.

Comment: Yes, I would like to change the content of the array. But I really want to understand accessing the values first.

Comment: have you tried writing the function in C, compiling it and looking at the assembler the compiler generates?